# Changing startKey and endKey of region servers of an existing table without deleting it?

Tags: hbase

Is there a way to change the start-key & end-key of region-servers in an existing HBase table.
Through hbase shell or any other way?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Region 1 : A -> B

Region 2 : C -> D

If you want for example to change Region 2 Start-key and end-key, You can merge it with the region 1 then split the result region :

```
merge_region 'region1_encoded_id’,'region2_encoded_id’
split ‘region1Name’
balancer
```

if region name is like : myHTable,,1414702482831.**13e9520e27a1f282e1da7f0779a89e08**.
your region_encoded_id will be : 13e9520e27a1f282e1da7f0779a89e08

Answer (score 0):

no there is nothing to edit the range of region, but you can use split and merge to end up with the result that you want.